# Why is line-ground voltage higher than line-line at the output of a variable frequency drive

Tags: power, three-phase

I am using a Fluke 87V, reading AC voltage with the low pass filter activated. I have also used a stray voltage eliminator and the readings are the same.

Between each of the phases I read about 38VAC. Between each of the phases and ground I read about 68VAC.

The VFD is connected to a load.

Could this be caused by voltages induced by ground loops? And how can I check to test if this is actually was is causing the strange readings?

Comment: The VFD first rectifies mains AC into DC, then "chops" that into 2, 4, or 8kHz pulses out to U, V, and W. The averages you're seeing do not show the whole picture - namely that U,V, and W pulses *overlap* slightly, which results in a lower phase-to-phase voltage reading as compared to phase-to-ground.

Comment: Do you measure any DC voltage to ground?

Comment: @rdtsc Doesn't the low pass filter on the meter eliminate this problem, the cutoff frequency of the filter is 1kHz.

Comment: @Andyaka There is a fluctuating DC voltage, I will go recheck and get some numbers. Thanks.